# How to transfer information between classes of windows in tkinter?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I want to transfer some of my user input in my main window to the toplevel window.

so far I have this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

class Level1 :
    def __init__(self, master):
    ## bunch of frames, labels and button instantiations
    ...........
    self.info = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    
    def get_info(self):
        return self.info

    def go_to_level2(self):
        self.level_2 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Level2(self.level_2)

class Level2: 
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(......)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text = Level1.get_info)
        self.label1.pack()
```

when I did this, it printed an instance or location of the memory like ..Ox.... Any idea to do transfer info to new window, or should I instantiate level2 inside level1?

Edit: displayed not printed (as in tk.Label)

Edit2: this is the solution:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

class Level1 :
    def __init__(self, master):
    ## bunch of frames, labels and button instantiations
    ...........
    self.info = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    
    def get_info(self):
        return self.info

    def go_to_level2(self):
        self.level_2 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Level2(self.level_2, self)

class Level2: 
    def __init__(self, master, level1):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(......)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text = level1.get_info())
        self.label1.pack()
```

Comment: There are no `print`s in the code you posted, so it's impossible to say why you got the output you did.  Generally speaking, you'd just pass additional parameters to `Level2`'s `__init__()` to give it access to anything from `Level1` it needs - that might be `Level1`'s `self`, or perhaps something more specific.

Comment: how can we pass a self of another class? isn't each class has its own self? and can only access its own self?

Comment: There's nothing keeping you from passing `self` as a parameter.  And if `Level2` stores that parameter, as `self.level1` perhaps, it can then do things like `self.level1.get_info()` to call methods of the other class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common solution is to pass the instance of the class with the data to the class that needs the data.

```
class Level1 :
    ...
    def go_to_level2(self):
        ...
        self.app = Level2(self.level_2, self)
        ...

class Level2:
    def __init__(self, master, level1):
        ...
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text = level1.get_info())
        ...
```

Comment: Nevermind, this works with just a little modification: text = level1.get_info() thank you!